# Obtener numero mayor y menor en Math Random con JList

Tags: java

quisiera exponerles una duda que tengo con el debido respeto; Tengo que realizar un programa que de 30 números aleatorios y que de ellos obtenga el numero mayor y menor.

Lo que hice para que me mostrara los números random fue poner la clase **Math Random** en un **JList** y ahora de esos números que obtuve quiero mostrar el numero mayor y menor pero no logro obtenerlos, ya he intentado algunas formas.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo? O deberia separar el **Math Random** del **Model** en el **JList**, esa es mi duda, muchas gracias de antemano.

```
package estadistica;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

/** @author Said */

public class Estadistica extends JFrame {
    
    Container contenedor;
    JButton btn1, btn2;
    JLabel lb1, lb2, lb3, lb4, lb5, lb6;
    JTextField txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4, txt5;
    JList listaNumeros;
    DefaultListModel model;
    JScrollPane scrollLista;
    
    // Metodo que permite iniciar el programa
    
    public Estadistica() {
        
        iniciarComponentes();
        setTitle("Estadistica Random");
        setSize(400, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      
    }

    private void iniciarComponentes() {
    
    //  Se instancia el contenedor donde se colocaran todos los atributos, nos permite poner su posicion y su tamaño.  
        
        contenedor=getContentPane();
        contenedor.setLayout(null);
        
    //  Atributos.  
        
        lb1 = new JLabel();
        lb1.setText("Estadistica de numeros Random");
        lb1.setBounds(100, 5, 400, 50);
        
        lb2 = new JLabel();
        lb2.setText("Numero Mayor:");
        lb2.setBounds(30, 150, 100, 30);
        
        lb3 = new JLabel();
        lb3.setText("Numero Menor:");
        lb3.setBounds(30, 200, 100, 30);

        lb4 = new JLabel();
        lb4.setText("Media:");
        lb4.setBounds(30, 250, 100, 30);
        
        lb5 = new JLabel();
        lb5.setText("Moda:");
        lb5.setBounds(30, 300, 100, 30);

        lb6 = new JLabel();
        lb6.setText("Desviacion:");
        lb6.setBounds(30, 350, 100, 30);        
        
        btn1 = new JButton("Generar");
        btn1.setBounds(30, 55, 100, 30);
        
        btn2 = new JButton("Borrar");
        btn2.setBounds(30, 500, 100, 30);        
        
        txt1 = new JTextField();
        txt1.setBounds(150, 150, 220, 30);
        
        txt2 = new JTextField();
        txt2.setBounds(150, 200, 220, 30);
        
        txt3 = new JTextField();
        txt3.setBounds(150, 250, 220, 30);
        
        txt4 = new JTextField();
        txt4.setBounds(150, 300, 220, 30);

        txt5 = new JTextField();
        txt5.setBounds(150, 350, 220, 30);        
        

    //  Lista
        
        listaNumeros = new JList();
        listaNumeros.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        // Instanciamos el modelo
        model = new DefaultListModel();

        // Instanciamos el Scroll que tendra la lista
        scrollLista = new JScrollPane();
        scrollLista.setBounds(150, 55, 220, 80);
        scrollLista.setViewportView(listaNumeros);

    //  Botones
        
        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                listanums();                   
            }
        });
        
        btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                borrarLista();
            }
        });         
        
    // Integracion de los atributos.
    
        contenedor.add(lb1);
        contenedor.add(lb2);
        contenedor.add(lb3);
        contenedor.add(lb4);
        contenedor.add(lb5);
        contenedor.add(lb6);        
        contenedor.add(btn1);
        contenedor.add(btn2);        
        contenedor.add(scrollLista);
        contenedor.add(txt1);
        contenedor.add(txt2);
        contenedor.add(txt3);
        contenedor.add(txt4);
        contenedor.add(txt5);
            
    }
    
    private void listanums() {
  
        int mayor= 0;
        int menor= 200;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            model.addElement((int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1));
            listaNumeros.setModel(model);           
        }      

    }

    private void borrarLista() {
        
        model.clear();
        txt1.setText("");
        txt2.setText("");
        txt3.setText("");
        txt4.setText("");
        txt5.setText("");
        
    }    
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Estadistica est = new Estadistica();
        
    }    
   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los número están en model, así que puedes iterarlo para hacer los cálculos que deseas, por ejemplo encontrar el mayor:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < model.size(); i++) {
       if (model.elementAt(i) > mayor) {
           mayor = model.elementAt(i);
       }
 }
```

Solo has un pequeño cambio en la declaración del model, agrega el tipo de dato para que no devuelva `Object`:

```
DefaultListModel<Integer> model;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme bro, fue de mucho ayuda tu respuesta puesto que es la solución al problema, un saludo y de nuevo muchas gracias.